# iPhone app activated before associated in-app-purchase activated?

Tags: iphone

I recently submitted my iPhone game for review.  I also approved the in-app-purchase for my game (and provided the in-app-purchase screenshot).  It's a few days later and the app status has been updated from "waiting for review" to "in review"... while the in-app-purchase status is still "waiting for review".  **Could the app go live in the store before the in-app-purchase?**  If so what happens when the user tries to make the in-app-purchase?  Anything the developer can do to remedy this?

Comment: This might be a better question for regular StackOverflow; it's strictly about a software development platform, and you're more likely to get someone who has dealt with something like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the app can go live without the in-app purchase being activated. To prevent this, you need to delay your app's release by setting the release date to some future date. Most iPhone devs will delay the release anyway so they can time press coverage, etc better. One bonus: you can give out promo codes to review sites between app approval and the release date.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a specific release date later to ensure that it is not released without the in-app-purchase content.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably noticed by now, but I thought I would add that you can now choose when you submit your app to:

- Release app into the app store as soon as it is approved.
- Ask from developer approval for release once it has been approved by Apple.

This means you don't have to play guessing games about when your app is going to be approved. Just set the flag and release when you are ready.